# I wrote the shared preferences code and it didn't work for me, what's the problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I wrote the shared preferences code and it did not work for me, I want it to move to a specific activity when the name is academic and the password is 123, and I want it to move to another activity when the name is admission and the password is 456. Where is the problem?

//this is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    name = findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
    password = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("login data", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

                editor.putString("username", name.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("MyPassword", password.getText().toString());
                editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                editor.apply();

            } else {
                editor.remove("username");
                editor.remove("MyPassword");
                editor.remove("checked");
                editor.apply();


            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "empty data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (name.getText().toString().equals(true_user_name_Admission) && password.getText().toString().equals(true_password_Admission)) {

                Intent l = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdmissionDashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(l);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Accessed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } else {
                if (name.getText().toString().equals(true_user_name_Academic) && password.getText().toString().equals(true_password_Academic)) {

                    Intent ad = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AcademicDashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(ad);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Accessed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    name.setError("Required");
                    password.setError("Required");
                }

            }

        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("login data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    name.setText(sp.getString("username", ""));
    password.setText(sp.getString("MyPassword", ""));
    checkBox.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("checked", false));

}
```

}

Comment: Button login;
    EditText name, password;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    String true_user_name_Academic = "Academic";
    String true_password_Academic = "123";
    String true_user_name_Admission = "Admission";
    String true_password_Admission = "456";

Comment: When trying to debug something like this, using a log or print statement is a simple way of seeing what is going on. Pull the values out into variables at the top of your `onClick` method and print them to see what is happening. `String n = name.getText().toString();` then `System.out.println("Name = " + n);`

Comment: You can do it without SharedPreferences ..

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
name = findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
password = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("login data", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

            editor.putString("username", name.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("MyPassword", password.getText().toString());
            editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
            editor.apply();

        } 
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "empty data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (name.getText().toString().equals(true_user_name_Admission) && password.getText().toString().equals(true_password_Admission)) {

            Intent l = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdmissionDashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(l);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Accessed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (name.getText().toString().equals(true_user_name_Academic) && password.getText().toString().equals(true_password_Academic)) {

                Intent ad = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AcademicDashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(ad);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Accessed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                name.setError("Required");
                password.setError("Required");
            }
    }

});
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    name.setText(sp.getString("username", ""));
    password.setText(sp.getString("MyPassword", ""));
    checkBox.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("checked", false));

}
```